# Using non ASCII characters when updating values in AWS SimpleDB returns SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-simpledb

I am developing an application that store some data in a Amazon SimpleDB instance. When doing update of values in this database I get an error from the API:

Array ( [curl] => [Errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Code] => SignatureDoesNotMatch [Message] => The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. [BoxUsage] => ) ) )

I have found out that this happens if I try to update the database with some non ASCII characters like "ØÆÅ". I have double checked that there is not something wrong with the timestamps used to generate the signature (like some questions on the topic at Stack Overflow suggests).

Can anyone confirm that SimpleDB does not support these characters? Does anyone got a workaround for this?

I am using a 3rd party library to access the database. It can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-sdb/

Edit:

Further investigation of the 3rd party library shows that all parameters are encoded using `rawurlencode()`. As far as I can see it also follows the requirements from Amazon that can be found in this article: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1928

So I am at loss on what to try next here.

Edit 2:

I think I might be closing in on the issue here. I got an iPhone application that uses the same PHP API to store the values as well. The application works fine when posting these non ASCII characters. In the application we set the "Content-Type" to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

I have found some articles describing the same:

http://chris.finne.us/2010/04/12/amazon-simpledb-signaturedoesnotmatch-error-when-putting-utf-8-characters-via-a-http-post/

http://groups.google.com/group/simple-record/browse_thread/thread/aa3cd430b35e8e1c?pli=1

I've tried to specify the `content-type` in my code, but have not been successful yet. The implementation uses the PHP function `curl` to do the request.
I have added this code to set the header, but it does not seem to do any difference:

```
($headers variable declared at the top of the class)
$this->headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
```

Comment: Added some information about that I think is the problem. I think one need to set the Content-Type on the request in order to make it work. Posting the non ASCII characters from the iphone through the same API works fine, while doing it from a php script does not.

Comment: Could it be an encoding problem?  You mention ASCII, but Amazon wants canonicalized UTF-8.  See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/HMACAuth.html

Comment: Yes everything points toward it being a encoding problem. I have been able to circumvent the problem by always making sure the values are posted to the script before posting them again to Amazon. This seems to somehow apply the correct content-type meta data and Amazon accept the characters. It is not the best solution, but given my timeframe for the project it will do.

Comment: Since UTF-8 is a strict super-set of US-ASCII, ASCII === UTF-8. However, if the data managed to get encoded as Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) or Windows-1252, you'll almost certainly run into problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I circumvented the problem by posting the data to a php script, then using this script to post the values to Amazon. This fixed the content type issues I had when reading the values directly from a cookie.

Answer (score -2):

Using 3rd party libraries is not a good idea, because if they have a bug, then it's harder to find it, than in your own code.

Comment: I assume you build everything completely from scratch, including your own operating system, compilers etc? Reinventing the wheel is rarely a good idea. Oh, and this really doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Yes I agree. I tend to use 3rd party libraries as often as I can. Provided that they are good ofc.